# Selenium Code: Specified URL is not opening

Tags: selenium

In the below code, the browser got opened but the URL is not typed by the script. Can anyone please suggest me the corrections needed for this script?

```
package SeleniumDemo;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class S {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
    WebDriver  DRIVER = new ChromeDriver();
    String URL = "http://www.facebook.com";
    DRIVER.manage().window().maximize();
    DRIVER.get(URL);
    System.out.println(DRIVER.getTitle());
    DRIVER.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.setProperty should point to you chrome driver location not chrome application

Comment: Thanks Nirjhar, It worked after pointing to the driver path.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have specified wrong path of `chromedriver.exe`. It should be `chromedriver.exe` not `chrome.exe`. Also, check your chrome browser version and based on that download chromedriver to execute your program.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
```

You can download chromdriver from below location:

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads